# Request for the proof of a result from Ramanujan's letter to Hardy.

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

[Srinivasa Ramanujan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) in his [first letter](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Of5G0r6DQiEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q&f=false) to [G.H. Hardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.H._Hardy) stated many results for which he didn't give proofs. Among them the result taken from [this link](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Of5G0r6DQiEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false) seems interesting :

- If $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{nx}}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}}-1} \ dx = \phi(n)$$ then $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{nx}}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}}-1} \ dx = \phi(n)-\frac{1}{2n} + \phi\biggl(\frac{\pi^2}{n}\biggr)\sqrt{\frac{2\pi^3}{n^3}}$.

The link also mentions that $\phi(n)$ is a complicated function. The following are certain special values and shows some values.

Questions which I would like to ask here are:

- Where can I find the proof of the above result?
- "*The following are certain special values*": Whats so special about the values?

Comment: Surely Bruce Berndt has documented these? The only question would be where.

Comment: "Special value of $\phi$" simply means that there might not be
a closed form for $\phi(n)$ for general $n$ but there are special cases where $\phi(n)$ can be evaluated.  For example, $\sin x$ has
the special value $(\sqrt{5}-1)/4$ at $x = \pi/10$,
and the $j$ function has the special value $66^3$ at $2i$.


Comment: @Noam: Thanks for the explanation. A small doubt: Here you say $\phi$ doesn't have a closed form, but you give an example of a function $\sin{x}$ which does seem to have a closed form.

Comment: @Charles: Yes even I thought Bruce Berndt's webpage should contain this. But I couldn't find it in his webpage, though what I did was the following: go to his publication page, search for papers which contain the title "Integral".

Comment: Usually 'closed form' refers to 'being able to write down a function in terms of elementary functions and no integrals'. One can write $Li(x)$ as an integral, but it is generally held to have no closed form. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks "@Charles Matthews". I did email Prof. Berndt (after seeing your comment) and he suggested me to look at this paper:

- *[Some definite integrals connected with Gauss's sums](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=oSioAM4wORMC&lpg=PA357&dq=Ramanujan%20collected%20papers&pg=PA59#v=onepage&q=Ramanujan%20collected%20papers&f=false)*, Mess. Math. 44 (1915), 75-85.

The result appears here in [Page 60.](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=oSioAM4wORMC&lpg=PA357&dq=Ramanujan%2520collected%2520papers&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q=Ramanujan%2520collected%2520papers&f=false) with proof.